# Localhost/phpmyadmin/ returns php code

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin, httpd.conf

But however after changing the "httpd.conf" directory from
index.html -> index.php I got this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPR1e.png

Then I tried using XAMPP and even after that I've gotten that screen.
Could someone tell me what I might be doing wrong?

Computer OS: Windows XP

Full Screen dump:
http://pastebin.com/Zbbxvxib

Comment: Your PHP isn't executed because Apache doesn't know how to do it. That's why you're getting raw PHP code instead of parsed code that produces HTML. If you tried using XAMPP, you'd have PHP working. Looks like you didn't shut down your old Apache before starting xampp.

Comment: The problem, as N.B. pointed out is that your apache isn't understanding that the file extension of the file it displayed has to be intrepreted by the PHP module. Make sure that your PHP module is loaded into apache and that the file extension of that file is linked to the PHP module. Checks steps 7 and 8 of the [PHP Installation Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php)

Comment: @MarcoPoli I was using this tutorial:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bb3z4oKkPCs
And it seems to have left out loading the PHP module into apache.
Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is (as suggested in the comments) Apache has no idea "how" to run php, so it is just giving you the raw php files.  You need to install PHP if you haven't, otherwise, if you have installed php you need to configure apache to use it.

## If PHP is NOT installed

Go ahead and google it, there are a ton of resources out there explaining how to do it.

A good thing to look for is the **WAMP stack**.  Which stands for Windows, Apache, MySQL & PHP.  There are many places showing you how to install each of these individual components.

## If PHP is installed

The `httpd.conf` file needs to be modified to include PHP.

Add the following line after all of the LoadModule statements:

```
LoadModule php5_module "[PathToPHP]/php5apache2_2.dll"
```

Search for AddType, and add the following after the last AddType line:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

Add the PHP location to the end of the httpd.conf file. For example, at the end of the file, add the following:

```
PHPIniDir "[PathToPHP]"
```

Comment: Thanks Kirk looks like this was what I was looking for. phpmyadmin now works for me now.

Thanks!

Comment: possible related, from [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/969882/509163) (php showing source code in localhost)