# Cannot access web interface of phpmyadmin after installing it

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have followed the instructions from this site after installing lamp server on ubuntu 14.04 - 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-14-04

When I type this in my webbrowser - localhost/phpmyadmin - the page is filled with php code.

Comment: It sounds like you didn't get Apache configured correctly or get the PHP module for it installed.  Can you post your httpd.conf file?

Comment: Yeah sure.. But could you check this out and tell me if i should do what is told in the first answer? - http://askubuntu.com/questions/387062/how-to-solve-the-phpmyadmin-not-found-issue-after-upgrading-php-and-apache

Comment: Ok I tried doing that but nothing worked.. guess I will put the httpd.conf.. But   could you tell me what really should i look for or edit in the httpd file so as to get it working instead of pasting all of it on the net ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to thank HeadCode for taking interest in my question.

The real problem was to find why localhost/phpmyadmin was returning php code. It depends on a lot of things but in my case the problem lied in the php5.conf file which resides in etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5-conf.

The php.conf file contents are as follows -

```
# Running PHP scripts in user directories is disabled by default
# 
# To re-enable PHP in user directories comment the following lines
# (from <IfModule ...> to </IfModule>.) Do NOT set it to On as it
# prevents .htaccess files from disabling it.
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
        php_admin_flag engine Off
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

As you can see if you want enable php you just have to comment the code  so that it looks something like this -

```
# Running PHP scripts in user directories is disabled by default
# 
# To re-enable PHP in user directories comment the following lines
# (from <IfModule ...> to </IfModule>.) Do NOT set it to On as it
# prevents .htaccess files from disabling it.
#<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
#    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
#        php_admin_flag engine Off
#    </Directory>
#</IfModule>
```

This addressed the issue at least for me.

Comment: Glad you figured it out, but you didn't say you were installing phpmyadmin in a home directory!

Comment: @HeadCode Correct me if I am wrong but I have installed it in var/www/html/*  This is where it is recommended ... Where else would you install it then?

Answer (score 0):

OK, this isn't really an answer but it's more than a comment.  In your httpd.conf file make sure you have this line and that it is not commented out:

```
LoadModule php5_module        modules/libphp5.so
```

That should be near the top of the file.  Much further down you'll see some AddHandler lines.  Make sure you have this:

```
 AddHandler php5-script .php
```

You also might want to look to make sure this directive is in place.  It gives Apache a clue for what file to try to serve if you navigate to a directory instead of a file:

```
 <IfModule dir_module>
     DirectoryIndex index.php
 </IfModule>
```

Don't forget to restart Apache after changing your httpd.conf file.

For your installation specifically make sure you have the following files:

```
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load
```

When you were going through the steps of installing your LAMP stack did you do the test of creating the info.php file?  I just created an Ubuntu 14.4 VM and followed all the steps and it worked for me the first time.  Try going back through all those steps and double checking everything.

Comment: I am not able to find the httpd file anywhere. Could you tell me how would i be able to edit the required file?  I have searched the apache 2 folder and i found the apache2.conf file. This seems to be the right solution but just that i cant find the httpd.conf file. Please help.

Comment: Ok i searched on the net and found out that httpd.conf has been scrapped and included in the apache.conf file. So now where do i add/change the modules you suggested?

Comment: I dont have the php5.conf and php5.load.. what do you suggest me to do to fix that?

Comment: It sounds like you didn't get your LAMP stack installed properly.  If you go back over the first set of directions here (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04), especially step 3 and 4, you will probably find where you went wrong.  Just for your information, I didn't install the optional PHP modules and I still got PHPMyAdmin to work, so the problem probably won't be with the optional modules.

Comment: I checked the info.php and its working just fine!! I think i just need to loadmodule and addhandler. Just i dont understand where to do it now.. i am sorry to bother you so much but i am not leaving this undone.. I have reinstalled everything and still doesnt work. :(

Comment: If info.php is working fine then you don't need to worry about  the AddHandler and LoadModule stuff.  If you see a bunch of information when you load info.php (and not the raw code) then you're fine as far as PHP and Apache go.  Are you still seeing the raw code when you try to load phpmyadmin?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. I found this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060995/localhost-phpmyadmin-returns-php-code  I think those modules only are causing trouble. You might wanna check this out too - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20739350/phpmyadmin-displays-code-not-web-page

Comment: That makes no sense.  Did you restart Apache after the phpmyadmin install?

Comment: Yes.. i do restart after every change and wherever required. I have done it a 100 times till now. Is .htaccess a problem? Like i haven't created it..but would it fix my problem? Edit: Sorry .htaccess is to strengthen security.

Comment: Does /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf exist? Do you now have /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf and /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load? Also, it's getting pretty late here and I'm logging off soon.  I will check back in the morning.