# localhost/phpmyadmin is returning some raw php code instead of login page

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin

I've installed php 7.3.8 and also Apache 2.4 on my windows 10 but the problem is when i try to load `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` i got some raw php code and i tried to edit httpd.conf file like this answer [Localhost/phpmyadmin/ returns php code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060995/localhost-phpmyadmin-returns-php-code)
but it didn't work out and also i couldn't run Apache anymore.
Now what should i do?
I tried to configure httpd.conf file just like that answer and I don't have `LoadModule php7` in my httpd.conf file.
Please notice that I'm new to php and apache and phpmyadmin and their stuffs :)

Comment: Did you connect (configure) Apache to know about PHP? It does not happen automatically. Sounds like you didnt do that yet.

Comment: Maybe you should uninstall Apache and PHP and MySQL if you have that Too and look at WAMPServer or XAMPP. With those you get Apache/PHP/MySQL all installed and configured for you (And they are free)

Comment: @RiggsFolly well, I'm using Apache only and i know i have to configure Apache to know PHP and I tried solutions and also i don't have sth LoadModlue php7 in httpd.conf file

Comment: Then APache does not know about PHP hence php is not being compiled and executed, it just gets sent like html to the browser